# Is is possible CONCATENATE 2 Choice columns? We want to display the descriptions next to the choices

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible CONCATENATE 2 Choice columns?  We want to display the descriptions next to the choices. There are 5 choices for the user to pick from in a New Item form.  The boss wants an elaborate description next to (to the right) each choice. I thought maybe I could make another choice column w/ the descriptions, then another calculated concatenated column to join them. Is that possible or reasonable? We have a no-code rule, so I can't use Designer or InfoPath. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a separate list

2) Add a calculated column (e.g. Full Title) with the following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE([Title]," - ",[description])
```

[image]

3) Use Full Title column as lookup column
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using a lookup column.  Make another list with your items and descriptions.  Then make a lookup to that list and select the description column for "add a column to show".